# How to display dots view on image slide

Tags: android

android studio said that it's not use for future app i.e. `Html.fromHtml("&#8226")` so i use this code but it's not work for me why is there any missing or...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;",1));
    dots[i].setTextSize(35);
    dots[i].setTextColor(colorInactive[position]);
    dotslayout.addView(dots[i]);
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem, can you be more clear

Comment: according to your code it should *not* work on devices lower that Android N

Comment: the main problem is the dots are not displaying on image slide @war_Hero